# Disabling SwiperJS carousel for tablet and mobile and showing all cards

Tags: swiper.js

Is it possible to disable the SwiperJS carousel for tablet and mobile? For desktop, we currently show four slides. Once the device is reduced to the size of a tablet or mobile, we want to disable the SwiperJS and show all the cards, stacked. Before writing custom code, we're wondering if there's a SwiperJS way to do this. Here's our current JS:

```
        init: false,
        slidesPerView: 'auto',
        watchOverflow: false,
        loop: false,
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        }, 
        breakpoints: {
            1200: {
                slidesPerView: 'auto',
            },
            720: {
                slidesPerView: 'auto',
                allowSlidePrev: false,
                allowSlideNext: false
            },
            300: {
                slidesPerView: 1,
            },
          },
    },
```